# Linq sql with inner query having group/order

Tags: entity-framework-core

We are using below linq:

```
            var query1 = from m in _appContext.TabEmployee
                      group m by m.AspUserID into g
                      select g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First();

            var query2 = from q in query1
                     join c in _appContext.TabCompany on q.AspUserID equals c.AspUserID
                     select c;

            var result = query2.ToList().AsQueryable();
```

But we are getting below error while running above code:

```
'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<TabEmployee>() could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

But if we change **query 1** to below, we do not get any errors:

```
            var query1 = from m in _appContext.TabEmployee
```

Here, we have removed the sql part which groups by AspUserID and takes first record in every group by ordering by Id column. We need this logic. What change do we need to make to fix above issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Please choose a tag that applies to the EF version you're using. LINQ-to-SQL is something quite different.

Comment: We are using Entity Framework Core 6 version.